# How to save data when Form1 closed & load the data into Tab Pages where User Control is used? C#

Tags: c#, user-controls, load, tabcontrol, autosave

I'm very new to programming & self learn C#. I'm trying to do a simple calculator to fit my own use but I stuck at data saved when Form1 Closed.

[Here's image to show the problem][1]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/PphO1.png

UserControl1 is loaded into tabPage1 & tabPage2 but to save data into Settings, only the last code will be used.
How to save data from each tabPages that used same UserControl1?

Here's my Form1 codes:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private UserControl1 userControl1;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        userControl1 = new UserControl1(); // add user control to tab page 1
        userControl1.Dock = DockStyle.Top;
        tabPage1.Controls.Add(userControl1);
        
        userControl1 = new UserControl1(); // add user control to tab page 2
        userControl1.Dock = DockStyle.Top;
        tabPage2.Controls.Add(userControl1);
    }

    private void Form1_FormClosed(object sender, FormClosedEventArgs e)
    {
        Properties.Settings.Default.textboxValue1 = UserControl1.instance.tbxValue1.Text; // save value1
        Properties.Settings.Default.textboxValue2 = UserControl1.instance.tbxValue2.Text; // save value2
        Properties.Settings.Default.Save();
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        UserControl1.instance.tbxValue1.Text = Properties.Settings.Default.textboxValue1; // load value1
        UserControl1.instance.tbxValue2.Text = Properties.Settings.Default.textboxValue2; // load value2
    }
}
```

Here's my UserControl1 codes:

```
public partial class UserControl1 : UserControl
{
    public static UserControl1 instance;
    public UserControl1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        instance = this;
    }

    int value1 = 0;
    int value2 = 0;
    int result = 0;
    private void btnRun_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Int32.TryParse(tbxValue1.Text, out value1);
        Int32.TryParse(tbxValue2.Text, out value2);
        result = value1 + value2;
        tbxResult.Text = result.ToString();
    }
}
```

Thanks guys.

Answer (score 0):

Guess this question is too easy for Pro. I had solved the problem. For those who are beginning self learn C#. Hope this answer can help you.

```
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    userControl**1** = new UserControl1(); // add user control to tab page1
    userControl**1**.Dock = DockStyle.Top;
    tabPage1.Controls.Add(userControl1);
    
    userControl**2** = new UserControl1(); // add user control to tab page2
    userControl**2**.Dock = DockStyle.Top;
    tabPage2.Controls.Add(userControl1);
}
```

Change userControl number will do the trick. And add each items into settings will do.

```
private void Form1_FormClosed(object sender, FormClosedEventArgs e)
{
    Properties.Settings.Default.textboxValue1 = **userControl1**.tbxValue1.Text; // save value1
    Properties.Settings.Default.textboxValue2 = **userControl1**.tbxValue2.Text; // save value2
    Properties.Settings.Default.Save();
}
```

Using **userControl1** can assign the items properties into Settings.

Have a good day.